# Copy HTML Canvas to PowerPoint

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I am trying to copy the canvas image from Chrome browser on to PowerPoint but it is not copying:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_grad

Can anyone confirm if this works for them?

**Note:** I am using a Windows laptop and Chrome version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit). Surprisingly any type of Canvas works flawlessly on my Mac's chrome to PowerPoint.

Comment: you can't copy a blob url to the operating systems clipboard

Comment: @JaromandaX, where do you get OP is trying to copy a blob URL ?

Comment: followed the link - right clicked the image, selected view image, saw it was a blob:, posted a comment saying as much

Comment: and ??? It's just an example of a gradient. There is no export made on the canvas, or am I missing an other link ?

Comment: but you're right ... there's zero code there that would make that image at all "copyable", i.e. as you say, no export - but my comment is quite correct, you can't copy that image

Comment: well right click "copy image" is doable on some UAs (at least chrome on mac, not on FF and I don't know about win & IE)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, Kaiido is correct, right click to copy image. That is the property of a Canvas. You don't need to make the image copyable. That's how canvas work in chrome.